# jQuery sortable and draggable table keeping the CSS style while dragging

Tags: jquery, css, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, css-tables

I need some help to keeping the CSS style (td width, etc) while performing a sortable or dragging movement.

My code so far:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cafc/75LxrwLw/4/)

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 30px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  min-width: 350px;
}
table tr th,
table tr td {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 5px;
}
table tr th:first-child,
table tr td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
}
table tr th {
  background: #eee;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
  text-align: left;
}

/* top-left border-radius */
table tr:first-child th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
}

/* top-right border-radius */
table tr:first-child th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}

/* bottom-left border-radius */
table tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}

/* bottom-right border-radius */
table tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
```

When I start dragging one row on table 1, the row loses the top border. How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

for that you should specify   `border-top: 1px solid #bbb;` too,you specified only `border-bottom` and `border-right` only

so the fix is

```
table tr th,
table tr td {
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
     border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sajadlfc/L5519syo/)

Comment: thanks!! but, now the borders of rows aren't 1px, but 2px. do understand what i mean?

Comment: @cafc:don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the tick mark sign left to my answer,i found that you have not accepted any answers..!!

Comment: sorry but, if I change the border-collapse from separate to collapse, the radius border table disappears... I need to keep radius border

Comment: @cafc:sorry mate,couldn't find a solution for that part,i will check and update

Comment: ok, thanks! mabye the solution is to put the border-top during the dragging movement event.... but i don't now to do that.. or if is there easer way...